# use php-array in ajax and post it back to php

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I there,
I try to use a php-array with ajax to POST it to another php-file.
I thought I could do it this way:

```
<?php
$test_array[] = "dum";
$test_array[] = "dim";
$test_array[] = "dam";
$test_array[] = "dom";
$test_array[] = "düm";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({ url: 'include.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { my_array : <?php echo json_encode($test_array); ?> 
                   },
        success: function(returnData)
             alert(returnData);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
    }

        }); 
}
</script>
```

with include.php looking like this:

```
echo count($_POST['my_array']);
echo json_decode($_POST['my_array']);
echo $_POST['my_array'];
```

The problem is, that no array is going to `incude.php`
The echos give "`1düm`", means, the length of the `$_POST-var` is 1 (while the original array is 5), and its entry is only "düm" (which is the last entry of the original array). 
It looks like this:

```
count:  1
json_decode:
$_POST:  düm
```

So, it seams that not the complete array, but only the last entry is POSTed...

How can I get the whole array `$test_array` to `include.php` via that ajax-call?

thx in advance...

Comment: Try to change your array to `$test_array['a'] = "dum"; $test_array['b'] = "dim";` and so on. Maybe that will help.

Comment: why should that make any difference, Gil?

Comment: Maybe it won't, but when you pour php into json and back, something might get lost in the process. Maybe the php gets the whole array but every value override the previous one so you're left with the last value inserted.

Comment: this is not the case...

Comment: Well, what do you get when you use `var_dump(json_decode($_POST['my_array']))`?

Comment: I get ´string(4) "düm"´

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49826/discussion-between-produnis-and-gil)

Comment: I couldn't continue but now I'm in front of a php station and my testings shows that `$_POST['my_array']` always contains the whole array. I checked it with a new and old version of jquery with no change, so I'm forced to give you the useless answer of "it's probably something on your side". Check the source page of the generated html if `my_array` receives the whole array. Besides that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: thx Gil, i found the error and posted my answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, make a javascript `Array` and pass it to ajax function

```
var myArr=["<?php print implode('","', $test_array)?>"];
$.ajax({ url: 'include.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { my_array : myArr 
                   },
        success: function(returnData)
             alert(returnData);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
    }

        });
```

and no need to `json_decode` in `include.php` anymore

Comment: with this, array-length is still 1, and content is all entries after another... thx for your answer, but this is not what I suspect to get...

Comment: thx again, but with your new code I get the same as with my code: array has length = 1 and entry is only "düm" (the last entry of the original array).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$test_array[] = "dum";
$test_array[] = "dim";
$test_array[] = "dam";
$test_array[] = "dom";
$test_array[] = "düm";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var stuff = <?php echo json_encode($test_array);?>;
        var jsonString = JSON.stringify(stuff);
    $.ajax({ url: 'include.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: {data : jsonString},
        success: function(returnData)
             alert(returnData);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
    }

        }); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

in ajax, change line:

```
my_array : <?php echo json_encode($test_array); ?>
```

into

```
my_array : JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($test_array); ?>)
```

So that it looks like this:

```
<?php
$test_array[] = "dum";
$test_array[] = "dim";
$test_array[] = "dam";
$test_array[] = "dom";
$test_array[] = "düm";
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.ajax({ url: 'include.php',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { my_array : JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($test_array); ?>) 
                   },
        success: function(returnData)
             alert(returnData);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("XMLHttpRequest="+XMLHttpRequest.responseText+"\ntextStatus="+textStatus+"\nerrorThrown="+errorThrown);
    }

        }); 
}
</script>
```

In `include.php` use

```
$my_array = json_decode($_POST['my_array'])
```

to get the array back.

However, this won't work with multidimensional arrays, for example, if the array looks like this:

```
$test_barry[1][1] = "1a";
$test_barry[1][2] = "1b";
$test_barry[1][3] = "1c";
$test_barry[2][1] = "2a";
$test_barry[2][2] = "2b";
$test_barry[2][3] = "2c";
$test_barry[3][1] = "3a";
$test_barry[3][2] = "3b";
$test_barry[3][3] = "3c";
```

you need to fetch back the multidimensional array in `input.php` with

```
$my_array = json_decode($_POST['my_array'],TRUE) // add TRUE
```

Comment: the clue was to use the php-array within the ajax-call as: JSON.stringify(<?php echo json_encode($test_array); ?>)